# Как вставить текст в EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin, edittext

Имеется `EditText`, который используется для поиска в RecyclerView. Я делаю голосовой поиск.

```
val result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)
search_edit_text.text = result[0]
```

Если использовать `TextView`, то всё работает, но с `EditText` `result[0]` выделяется красным. Я пришёл к выводу, что `EditText` можно изменять самому, но вставить какой-либо текст при нажатии на кнопку нельзя.

`search_edit_text.text = "text"` тоже не работает.
Может быть вы знаете способ, как вставить текст в `EditText` при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: search_edit_text.setText(result[0]) попробуйте

Comment: @Cypher помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть [вставка текста на позицию курсора](https://russianblogs.com/article/3656496211/).

Можно будет добавить этот код в событие onClick.

Либо, есть вариант:

```
EditText.setText(EditText.getText().toString() + "ваш текст");
```